# Как получить тип населенного пункта в геокодере яндекса

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Ответ геокодера содержит kind:locality. Так обозначаются все населенные пункты(города, деревни, поселки и т.п.). Есть ли возможность отличить город от деревни?

Answer (score 1):

В [Геокодере 1.x](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/?from=SO) такой возможности пока нет.